# Difference between Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Iroha?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Both Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Iroha are platforms for building distributed ledger applications.

What are the main differences between them? When to choose one over the other to implement a blockchain solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hyperledger Iroha and Fabric are just 2 of 5 independent Hyperledger blockchain technologies:

- [Hyperledger Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/whatis.html#hyperledger-fabric)
- [Hyperledger Sawtooth](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/introduction.html#distinctive-features-of-sawtooth)
- [Hyperledger Indy](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/projects/indy) (Identity Management focus)
- [Hyperledger Iroha](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/) (Extensive client API support, including mobile platforms)
- [Hyperledger Burrow](https://github.com/hyperledger/burrow/blob/master/README.md) (Ethereum EVM implementation)

How is Iroha different?

- Byzantine fault tolerant consensus algorithm (called YAC) is high-performance and allows for finality of transactions with low latency.
- Includes built-in commands for common tasks such as create digital assets, register accounts, and transfer assets between accounts.
- Has a robust permission system, allowing permissions to be set for all commands, queries, and joining of the network.

I would evaluate each technology to see which one best fits your needs.

Comment: when you say Iroha is Mobile app focused does it mean that it will create a node on the mobile network itself?

Comment: No. The client resides on the mobile phone. It uses the data network (Internet) to connect to backend servers. Here's a link to more information: https://iroha.tech/

Comment: @DanAnderson 's comment had an outdated link..... here is the new one https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/master/develop/cases.html

Comment: new link https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/develop/develop/cases.html

Answer (score 4):

Fabric and Iroha are different Hyperledger technologies.

- Unlike Fabric where peers polls for validation, Iroha applications interacts with peers in a simple client-server fashion.
- Iroha uses YAC consensus algorithm.
- The most significant difference is provided by the entity called accounts. Accounts have roles associated with them and only those accounts that holds grantable permission can perform any actions.

I don't know about your use case, so I'll generalise using a small example here. Go for Iroha in use cases similar to KYC. Iroha specialises in accounts and roles(set of permissions) associated with it.
 You can handle similar scenario with Fabric too, but then you need to take care about access rights, grants etc.  Similarly, various use cases can be solved using multiple technologies. 
 Iroha would also be preferable in scenarios involving creation and transfer of assets.
[This](https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases/) will be helpful for you. Cheers!